# How to create a GRE tunnel on Mac OSX Lion?

Tags: macos, interface, routes, tunneling

i'm trying to find a way to create a GRE Tunnel on osx lion, i'm able to create such tunnels in almost every os, including: openbsd/freebsd, linux and cisco IOS.

I'm very surprised that this subject is not discussed in any related osx threads over knowledge sources, ie. google, forums and QA sites.

I found only a couple questions on forums without answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: The project at http://code.google.com/p/mac-gre/ has been updated and compiles under 10.8 as of Oct 2012. I just compiled it and installed.

Answer (score 0):

According to Note 8 in http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1629,

> 8.For Mac OS X Server v10.3 VPN service: PPTP uses the IP-GRE protocol (IP protocol 47).

So, GRE should be implemented in the kernel, but I'm not seeing where you can set up your own tunnel, other than using the built-in PPTP service.

Comment: Its very odd that osx doesn't support gre interfaces, in bsd flavors we just need to create the interface with ifconfig.